# CSS AND HTML NOT LINKING IN Sublime text 3 after trying everything

Tags: html, css

I im using sublime text 3 to create a google page replica as practice with html and css. This is my first project as I am new to programming. I have gone through countless other posts about this issue and have tried everything suggested but still to no avail I am unable to link my html and css. Please advise

html.index and style.css are in the same root directory.

HTML CODE:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Thnx in advance

Comment: It's hard to say anything from the given information. Please try to create a reproducible problem. Thanks

Comment: All else being equal, that will work. You need to provide a reproducible test case and do some debugging. Run the HTML and CSS through validators. Check the Network tab in the browser's Developer Tools to make sure the file is being requested and contains what you expect.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just a typo error, but it should be index.html and not what you typed (html.index) and also it'll help if you could post the snippet of code from you html.index file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, check your file name it must be index.html, not html.index.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
</head>

<dev id="navbar">

Comment: Sorry that was a Typo I do have it saved as index.html ran it through the console in Chrome gave no errors.